# Solve $9^x+6^x=2^{(x+1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a math teacher and cannot for the life of me figure out how to algebraically solve this equation:

$$9^x+6^x=2^{(x+1)}$$

This question is intended for precalculus honors students. Clearly, $x=0$ is a solution. I believe it's the only one since it can be shown that $9^x+6^x< 2^{(x+1)}$ for $x<0$ and $9^x+6^{x} > 2^{(x+1)}$ for $x>0$. Is this reasoning the only way to solve the equations without graphing or using a solver? I also tried writing all of the $3^x$ as $2^{x\log_2{3}}$ but that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: $x=0$ is the only solution

Comment: $\left(\frac{9}{6}\right)^x+1=2\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^x$. The left side is strictly increasing, the right side is strictly decreasing.

Comment: @user236182 Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: $(4.5)^x+(3)^x$ is clearly increasing then for $x\gt 0$ is greater than $2$ and for $x\lt 0$ is less than $2$.

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting my comment as an answer. $$\left(\frac{9}{6}\right)^x+1=2\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^x$$ The left side is strictly increasing, the right side is strictly decreasing. Therefore there exists at most one real solution. You know $x=0$ is a solution, therefore it's the only real solution. You can sometimes use intermediate value theorem to prove a real solution exists and where it is.

Answer (score 1):

$$9^x+6^x=2^{(x+1)}\iff (4.5)^x+(3)^x=2$$
It is evident that a solution is $x=0$. Why is it the only possible solution?